# Breeding chickens in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can anyone tell me how to breed chickens in Minecraft PE? I did it once but am not sure how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chickens can be bred like other farm animals, by feeding any two adult chickens with wheat seeds, melon seeds, or pumpkin seeds. After breeding, chickens will not accept any more food for about 5 minutes.

Chicks can also be produced by breaking eggs. The eggs must be explicitly broken; eggs sitting around as items will not hatch, and will eventually despawn like other items. Note that there is a very small chance that eggs will actually produce chickens.

When an egg is thrown it will eventually hit a solid block or a mob, and break. It then it has a 1/8 chance to spawn a baby chicken; if it does, there is a 1/32 chance of spawning 4 chicks instead of one. If the egg was thrown at a wall at certain angles, the chicken may spawn in the wall and either suffocate (opaque blocks) or pass through entirely (transparent blocks).

From the wiki